# XSL-FO and correct use of xsl:template and xsl:for-each

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xsl-fo

below you can see the XML and the XSL I am trying to format it with. It all worked fine until I tried to insert the template. Obviously I am doing something wrong. I am trying to use **template** and **for-each** to add a row in the table for each `<order_line_item>` nested under `<order_line_items>` and in each of the four cells there should be the four values nested under `<order_line_item>` Could you help? Thanks!

```
    <hash>
    <order_line_items type="array">
        <order_line_item>
                <document_currency_unit_price_after_discount_value amount="300.0" code="GBP">£300.00</document_currency_unit_price_after_discount_value>
                <document_currency_net_after_main_discount amount="300.0" code="GBP">£300.00</document_currency_net_after_main_discount>
                <description>Subscription</description>
                <unit_quantity type="decimal">1.0</unit_quantity>
        </order_line_item>
        <order_line_item>
            <document_currency_unit_price_after_discount_value amount="300.0" code="GBP">£200.00</document_currency_unit_price_after_discount_value>
                <document_currency_net_after_main_discount amount="300.0" code="GBP">£200.00</document_currency_net_after_main_discount>
                <description>Additional Services</description>
                <unit_quantity type="decimal">1.0</unit_quantity>
        </order_line_item>
        <order_line_item>
            <document_currency_unit_price_after_discount_value amount="300.0" code="GBP">£-50.00</document_currency_unit_price_after_discount_value>
                <document_currency_net_after_main_discount amount="300.0" code="GBP">£-50.00</document_currency_net_after_main_discount>
                <description>Discount</description>
                <unit_quantity type="decimal">1.0</unit_quantity>
        </order_line_item>
    </order_line_items>
</hash>
```

XSL

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xslt:stylesheet xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times" xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings" xmlns:xslt="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xf="http://www.ecrion.com/xf/1.0" xmlns:xc="http://www.ecrion.com/2008/xc" xmlns:xfd="http://www.ecrion.com/xfd/1.0" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" extension-element-prefixes="date str">
  <xslt:output indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <fo:root font-size="9pt">
      <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="A4" page-width="210mm" page-height="297mm">
           <fo:region-body region-name="xsl-region-body" padding-top="0px" padding-bottom="0px" padding-left="0px" padding-right="0px" margin-top="15mm" margin-bottom="15mm" margin-left="1.5cm" margin-right="1.5cm" border-style="none" border-width="0px" border-color="" background="" background-repeat="no-repeat" background-position-horizontal="0px" background-position-vertical="0px" extent="0px" column-gap="0px" column-count="1" reference-orientation="0"/>
           <fo:region-before region-name="xsl-region-before" display-align="after" extent="15mm" padding-top="0px" padding-bottom="0px" padding-left="0px" padding-right="0px" border-style="none" border-width="0px" border-color="" background="" background-repeat="no-repeat" background-position-horizontal="0px" background-position-vertical="0px" reference-orientation="0"/>
           <fo:region-after region-name="xsl-region-after" display-align="before" extent="15mm" padding-top="0px" padding-bottom="0px" padding-left="0px" padding-right="0px" border-style="none" border-width="0px" border-color="" background="" background-repeat="no-repeat" background-position-horizontal="0px" background-position-vertical="0px" reference-orientation="0"/>
           <fo:region-start region-name="xsl-region-start" extent="1.5cm" padding-top="0px" padding-bottom="0px" padding-left="0px" padding-right="0px" border-style="none" border-width="0px" border-color="" background="" background-repeat="no-repeat" background-position-horizontal="0px" background-position-vertical="0px" reference-orientation="0"/>
           <fo:region-end region-name="xsl-region-end" extent="1.5cm" padding-top="0px" padding-bottom="0px" padding-left="0px" padding-right="0px" border-style="none" border-width="0px" border-color="" background="" background-repeat="no-repeat" background-position-horizontal="0px" background-position-vertical="0px" reference-orientation="0"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
      </fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4">
        
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">

<fo:table margin-bottom="5mm">
                <fo:table-column column-width="25%"/>
                <fo:table-column column-width="25%"/>
                <fo:table-column column-width="25%"/>
                <fo:table-column column-width="25%"/>
                    <fo:table-body>
                        <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block>
                                Product
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block>
                                Quantity
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block>
                                Unit Price
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block>
                                Net Amount
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                      </fo:table-row>
                    <xsl:template match="hash/order_line_items">
                      <fo:table-row>
                      <xsl:for-each select="order_line_item">
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block>
                                <xsl:value-of select="description">
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block>
                                <xsl:value-of select="document_currency_unit_price_after_discount_value">
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block>
                                <xsl:value-of select="document_currency_unit_price_after_discount_value">
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block>
                                <xsl:value-of select="unit_quantity">
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                      </fo:table-row>
                    </xsl:template>
                </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>
 </fo:flow>
      </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>  
  </xsl:template>
 </xslt:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Templates cannot be nested. Use either a single template with nested `xsl:for-each` instructions, or multiple templates with the `xsl:apply-templates` instruction passing the next level of nodes to the next template.

Comment: @michael.hor257k thanks, I get the gist, but would you be able to give me an example? Unfortunately this is not my cup of tea, but I need to get it sorted for work nonetheless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I stated in the comments, templates cannot be nested. You need to use either a single template with nested `xsl:for-each` instructions, or multiple templates with the `xsl:apply-templates` instruction passing the next level of nodes to the next template.

In the given example, you only need one template, with a single `xsl:for-each` instruction to create a table row for each `order_line_item`. Since you want to populate the cells in the rows in a different order than the one used in the input, it would be best to populate them individually.

Here is a **simplified** example (creating an HTML table):

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/hash">
    <table>
        <!-- header row -->
        <tr>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Unit Price</th>
            <th>Net Amount</th>
        </tr>
        <!-- data rows -->  
        <xsl:for-each select="order_line_items/order_line_item">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="unit_quantity"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="document_currency_unit_price_after_discount_value"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="document_currency_net_after_main_discount"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```